# Force exerted on electron with spin in uniform magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin

Assume that an electron with spin moves in a uniform magnetic field along the same direction as the field, then what's the force exerted on the electron? Does the electron with spin aligned with the magnetic field move more easily?

Comment: What problem are you having calculating this yourself? Do you know what force a magnetic field exerts on a charge? Do you understand that spin gives the electron a magnetic dipole moment? Do you know what force a magnetic field exerts on a magnetic dipole moment?

Comment: I'm considering current induced magnetization which is in the same direction as the electric field. If I replace the current with spin aligned current, what will happen.  Usually, we consider the Lorentz force for charge in magnetic field. The force is perpendicular to the magnetic field. Electron with spin has a magnetic moment of  $\hbar/2$. For the last question, I'm not clear. It seems there need to be a magnetic field gradient to exert a force on the magnetic dipole moment?

Comment: Yes, there must be a gradient. So in your scenario, there is no force either on the charge (because velocity is parallel to field) or on the dipole moment (because field is uniform).

Comment: *Electron with spin has a magnetic moment of ℏ/2* No, that doesn’t have the correct dimensions to be a magnetic dipole moment.

Comment: Oh, yes, $\hbar/2$ should be the angular momentum, and the magnetic moment is about $e\hbar/2m$.